# Heroku + Node.js Deployment: H10 Crash - Cannot find module ./lib/websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

On my local machine, running my Node.js project works perfectly fine. But when I deploy my app to Heroku, I get an H10 error with the following message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/websocket'
```

Below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mazebattles",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "multiplayer maze competition",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "mazes",
    "multiplayer",
    "game",
    "race"
  ],
  "author": "henryzhu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "easytimer.js": "^2.4.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socketio": "^1.0.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  }, 
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by not deploying node_modules. Apparently, Heroku automatically deploys node_modules for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this when a dependency is in devDependencies. Your stack trace should help and you figure out which module to look at.